# How many ideals in the number field $\mathcal O_K=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ corresponding to norm $18=3^2\cdot 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$, so $\mathcal O_K=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$.

This requires the follow-up question because the norm is now not squarefree.

So now the question how many ideals we can find in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$ corresponds to norm $18$

Now $(2)= (2,1+\sqrt{-5})^2=\mathfrak p^2$ and $(3)= (3,1+\sqrt{-5})(3,1-\sqrt{-5})=\mathfrak q \mathfrak q'$

So can we say that any ideal norm $18$ should be combination of $\mathfrak p, \mathfrak q, \mathfrak q'$? I think no, because if we eliminate one of them the norm should drop (since $(2)$ is ramified and has no couple prime ideal with the same norm which can replace it in a possible combination).

So how to attack this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let $I \subset O_K$ be an ideal of norm $18$. Let $\mathfrak{r} \supset I$ be a prime ideal, then the norm of $\mathfrak{r}$ (a power of its residue characteristic) divides the norm of $I$ which is $18$, so the residue characteristic of $\mathfrak{r}$ is $2$ or $3$, so $\mathfrak{r}$ is $\mathfrak{p}$, $\mathfrak{q}$ or $\mathfrak{q}’$.

It follows that $I$ can be written as $\mathfrak{p}^a\mathfrak{q}^b(\mathfrak{q}’)^c$ for some integers $a,b,c \geq 0$.

Then use the norm to find how many triples $(a,b,c)$ do the trick.